# Android button setBackground colour without size changing

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I added 7x7 button set to a table TableLayout by code, everything is good before I want to set a background colour to a button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0ANA.png)

after I set background colour the button becomes bigger than before..

here is my code

```
private void initGameBoard(){

    mTableLayout= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);

    int counter = 1;
    for(int row=0;row<7;row++) {
        TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
        for(int col=0;col<7;col++) {

            mTableLayout.setColumnShrinkable(col, true);

            Button button=new Button(this);

            button.setTag(counter);

            if (counter == 2){

                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }

            tableRow.addView(button);

            counter++;

        }

        mTableLayout.addView(tableRow, new LayoutParams(FP, WC));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting button background color, try this..

button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);